# Converting NSMutableArray to float array

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray, parameter-passing

I have a string with lat and lon seperated by ",":

```
 NSArray* coord = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

 NSMutableArray *lat= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray *lon = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for(int i=0;i<[coord count]-1;i=i+2)

    {


          [lat addObject:[coord objectAtIndex:i]];
          [lon addObject:[coord objectAtIndex:i+1]];

    }
```

and I want to use them with this function:

```
 int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
int i, j, c = 0;
for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
        (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
        c = !c;
}
return c;
```

}

So the NSMutableArray are not working. So I created this one:

```
 //Seperating the string with coordinates by ","
    NSArray* coord = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    float *lat = malloc(sizeof(float) * ([coord count]/2));
    float *lon = malloc(sizeof(float) * ([coord count]/2));


    for(int i=0;i<[coord count]-1;i=i+2)

    {

        lat[i]= [[coord objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        lon[i]= [[coord objectAtIndex:i+1] floatValue];


    }
   free(lat);
    free(lon);
```

which gives me some errors like: (5629,0xacc3da28) malloc: *** error for object 0x714c490: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use the values inside the arrays
to get to such a value you can use objectAtIndex as in: 
`[arrayName objectAtIndex:index];`
If you really want to give an NSMutableArray as parameter you should do it this way:
`functionName: (NSMutableArray *) arrayName`

Comment: Actually  I dont want to change the function. It gives me error when replacing the verity[j] with [vert objectAtIndex:j]

Comment: @user776720 You're grabbing a good C book and reading it *now.* Then repeat with an Objective-C one. `float`s aren't objects.

Comment: lat[i]= [[coord objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]; Objects can be converted to floats

Comment: you should check if j is smaller than the length of the array.

Comment: you should also check if the array is properly initialized

Comment: A NSMutableArray Shouldn't give any problems it works just fine I could help you if I knew how the values in the array relate to the parameters in the function if i know what fits where i can give you a more detailed solution.

Comment: ok float vertx is for *lat and verty for *lon. nvert is [lat count] and the other two are statics

Answer (score 0):

Given the other information i think you want this.

Considering you have established NSMutableArray *lat and NSMutableArray *lon
where lat and lon have as much values which are not nil or null.

```
for(int i=0;i<lat.count;i++)
{
    pnpoly(lat.count, [lat objectAtIndex:i], [lon objectAtIndex:i], static, static);
}
```